Send a 'wake on LAN' packet from PC laptop to Mac laptop over WiFi
I want to send a wake on lan packet from a windows 11 laptop to a Macbook. I've found a short python script that opens a socket, in initializes the 'magic" command and then sends that command to the MAC address of the Mac. Both computers are on the same subnet and are connected using WiFi. The program is
import socket

def wol(luna_mac_address: bytes) -> None:
    """Send a Wake-on-LAN magic packet to the specified MAC address."""
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    magic = b"\xff" * 6 + luna_mac_address * 16
    s.sendto(magic, ("<broadcast>", 7))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Pass to wol the MAC address of the Ethernet port of the appliance to wake up
  wol( b'\x20\xc9\xd0\xc6\x22\x12')

The Mac has been configured to allow itself to be woken on lan active but it didn't work when the script was run. To see if the packet was getting out, I ran wireshark on the PC and started a capture on the WiFi device. I set the display filter to only show packets with the MAC address shown in the code. When the script was run again, the packet wasn't shown. The return value from the sendto function showed 102 bytes being sent which is the correct length. I removed the filter but the magic packet was still missing.
Is the problem because of the Wifi connection or is there an adaptor issue that is blocking the packet?

Try sending it as a unicast instead of a broadcast. Broadcasts and multicasts are tricky on Wi-Fi, especially with sleeping clients.
